# REST url for nested resources

Tags: rest

Which is a proper way of creating REST path ? 
Say i have REST resource like,

`base_url/api/projects/{projId}/sprints/{sprintId}/.....etc`

I have more than 5 path params like this in a resource url. Is it proper to have so many path params or we have to cut it to different resources like,

```
base_url/api/projects/{projId}
base_url/api/sprints/{sprintId}
...etc
```

The condition here is , a sprint cannot exist without a project and so on. If we need to cut the resources to different paths, are there any standards on which conditions we can cut them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) doesn't care about the URI design. **That's a misconception.**

The readability of a URI is *desirable* but not mandatory in the REST architectural style.

---

As defined in the [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), the URI syntax is organized hierarchically, with components listed in order of decreasing significance from left to right separated by `/`. If a *sprint* cannot exist without a *project*, you can use the following to express such *hierarchy*:

```
/api/projects/{project-id}/sprints/{sprint-id}
```

However, if the URI gets too long and you have many parameters to pass around, there's not issues in splitting it:

```
/api/projects/{project-id}
```

```
/api/sprints/{sprint-id}
```